# Simplify Difference of Conjugate Pairs

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex

Is it possible to easily simplify the difference of conjugate pairs?

In particular, if there's just a single variable, then

```
FullSimplify[a - Conjugate[a]]
```

> ```
> 2 I Im[a]
> ```

But trying to do the same thing with a slightly more complex expression fails:

```
FullSimplify[a Conjugate[b] - Conjugate[a] b]
```

> ```
> a Conjugate[b] - Conjugate[a] b
> ```

I have found one solution (answered below) but it relies on a `FullSimplify` which doesn't seem very optimal.

Comment: `ComplexExpand[a Conjugate[b] - Conjugate[a] b, {a, b}]` ?

Comment: That is indeed mathematically equivalent, but it usually results in quite a large expression.  I was really hoping to get the result as `2 I Im[...]`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution which works to some extent, though it relies on a `FullSimplify` to determine whether the rule should be applied which could be quite slow.

```
1 / (2 I) {
  a - Conjugate[a],
  a Conjugate[b] - Conjugate[a] b,
  a b Conjugate[c] Conjugate[d] - c d Conjugate[a] Conjugate[b],
  a b c d - Conjugate[a b c d]
  } /. {
   a_ - b_ :> 2 I Im[a] /; FullSimplify[Conjugate[a] == b]
 }
```

> ```
> {Im[a], Im[a Conjugate[b]], Im[a b Conjugate[c] Conjugate[d]], Im[a b c d]}
> ```